# Affiliate Window API integration in PHP

Tags: php, affiliate, affiliates

I am trying to write an application that integrates with the Affiliate Window API. The only problem I have is I have literally 0 experience in php and so find myself unable to debug even the most elementary of issues.

I downloaded the below code which is supposed to be a sample application. Unfortunately running it fails at the first hurdle:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/ravinthambapillai/Downloads/api.client/listmerchants.php on line 9
```

This is the error message I get when I run the below:

Can anyone help me with what I need to fix to get this right?

```
<?php
define('API', 'PS');
require_once('constants.inc.php');
require_once('classes/class.ClientFactory.php');
$oClient = ClientFactory::getClient(REDACTED, REDACTED, merchant);
$listmerchants = array('iCategoryId'=> 97, 'iMaxResult' => 10);
echo 'hello world';
    $oResponse= $oClient->call('getMerchantList', $listmerchants);
    foreach($oResponse->oMerchant as $details){
        $name = $details->sName;
        $strapline = $details->sStrapline;
        $description = $details->sDescription;
        $logo = $details->sLogoUrl;
        $showurl = $details->sDisplayUrl;
        $deeplink = $details->sClickThroughUrl;
        $id = $details->iId;

        if ($logo<>'') {
            echo "<a href=".$deeplink."  title='".$name."'><img src=".$logo.
            " style='float:left; margin:5px;' alt='".$name.
            " :: ".$strapline." :: ".$description." :: ".$showurl.
            "' width=\"88\" height=\"31\" border=\"0\"></a>";
        }

    }


?>
```

Comment: Basically your error implies that `$oResponse->oMerchant` is not an array of objects that is needed for the foreach loop to work. Which mean your call in the line before has failed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the constants in constants.inc.php?

API_USERNAME needs to be set to your account ID, and API_PASSWORD needs to be set to your Affiliate API Password as seen at https://www.affiliatewindow.com/affiliates/accountdetails.php (when you're logged in)